# To clear browsing history in IE like form data, cookie using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

can any one let me know

how to delete IE Form data from browsing history using java script?

Please tell how to get browsing history data using java script

Thanks in Advance......!

For your More information, i want to delete already existing for data like (arunkandasamy name from the below image)

[image]

If i want to to delete this form information manually in IE manns,
 Tool -> Internet Option -> Delete Browsing history -> FormData ->delete

Is it possible to delete this form data using java script?

I hope this information able to catch the exact my probelm....

Thanks u friends....

Hi Friend,

Thanks for your valuable inputs
I got answer.
In HTML, while using "autocomplete = off" form data value is removed....

Thanks to all....

Comment: I hope the answer is "You can't", because it would be a security breach. Unless you are talking about a cookie associated with _your_ site?

Comment: I have posted a response but without more detail I am voting to close. Update the question with the specific problem you are trying to solve and perhaps there is a better solution. Usually relying on the ability to manipulate the browser is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

> how to delete IE Form data from browsing history using java script?

Set cache expiration headers; this doesn't remove the items from history but forces the page in question to reload. Truly clearing the browser history is a user action.

> Please tell how to get browsing history data using java script

History data is not available with JavaScript, other than the ability to *navigate* immediate history.

Answer (score 0):

For safety purpose, history data is not accessible to Javascript, but it provide a history object to make current page back or forward.

```
history.go();
history.forward();
```